# Grails: How to trigger submit or call to action when input is changed

Tags: grails

The page that I'm working on involves a table and datepicker. If I change the value of the date, it should pass the date to the index action and re-query from DB. And display the newly queried data from DB. In other words, datepicker serves as a filter.

I made a change event for the datepicker, if the data is changed this will trigger an ajax call to index. It was able to get the correct data but could not display it properly. Grails returns the whole page. It does not update the page.

Here's my controller:

```
def index() {

    def currentCompany = sessionService.company
    def Long countryId = params.countryId ? params.countryId as Long : currentCompany.countryId;

    java.text.DateFormat format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    Date startDateValue = (params.startDate == null || params.startDate.isEmpty() ) ? null : format.parse(params.startDate)
    Date endDateValue = (params.endDate == null || params.endDate.isEmpty() ) ? null : format.parse(params.endDate)

    def exchangeRateList = exchangeRateService.getFilteredExchangeRate(countryId, startDateValue , endDateValue)
    def currencyList = cacheService.currencies

    params.max = 10
    params.countryId = countryId
    respond ("", model : [
                    exchangeRateInstanceList : ListUtil.list(exchangeRateList, params),
                    exchangeRateInstanceCount : exchangeRateList.size(),
                    currencyInstanceList : currencyList
            ]);
}
```

Could you tell me how to trigger call to index action when input test is changed using Grails?

Comment: You should really post the relevant gsp for this to be answered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use remoteFunction to run action from controller: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html